# Redshift psql regex how to match consecutive repeated number?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, amazon-redshift, psql

In redshift psql, I want to find strings that has 3 consecutive repeated numbers such as "000", "111", "222",... "999".

Currently I could only use `select col from my_table where col similar to '%000|111|222|333|444|555|666|777|888|999%'`, but I'm looking for simplified solution.

I have checked some online solutions such as `select col from my_table where col similar to '%([0-9])(\1)(\1)%'`, but simply could not match any consecutive repeated numbers...

Is there any simplified solution?

Comment: Frankly, the `SIMILAR TO` is simpler than using a Regex expression and is likely to execute faster (but it would be a minor speed improvement compared to the cost of disk access). Is the current method causing you a problem?

Comment: I haven't cost me any problem yet. But when using `similar to` we can use regex, so I was wondering whether there's simiplified regex version here with `similar to`. Cuz when my colelagues are doing the code review, they might say it's not simplified enough..

Comment: Frankly, the current version is more "obvious" as to what it is doing. The regex version takes quite a bit of thinking to realise what it is (meant to be) doing. Simpler is better when it comes to supportability. In looking through the Redshift [Pattern-Matching Conditions - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions.html), there doesn't seem to be the "`\1`" group reference capability. You could create a Scalar User-Defined Function to hide what it's doing, but I don't see any benefit of that unless it is referenced in many different queries.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this in Redshift?